# How do I define a constant equal to -2147483648?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a chunk of code generated by a script, and the code involves some integer constants. I ran into a strange problem: one of the constants is equal to -2147483648 (minimum signed int32), and Visual Studio generates the following *error*: `unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned` (which is especially strange since I don't have treat warnings as errors enabled).

Apparently it sees an integer that doesn't fit in the signed type, makes it unsigned, and only then applies the unary minus. I suppose the result would still be correct as it will be casted to `int` (which is actually a template argument), but I'd like to avoid the warning. Is it just a VS feature or does the standard have anything to say about it?

Here's the offending line:

```
typedef Proto_Int<-2147483648,32> Typeinfo_77;
```

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but there are constants for max and min "types" in the standard: `std::numeric_limits<int>::min();`  and `std::numeric_limits<int>::max();` See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

Comment: That's why I mentioned that it is generated by a script. The constant is read from a file, and it (normally) has nothing to do with numeric limits.

Comment: If it's "read from a file" as you describe.. How exactly did you get it as a "Template" argument as shown above? I answered the question in the title, I suppose. Not the question about whether the standard has anything to say about it. MSDN says: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kh09110.aspx

Comment: I have a python script which generates a large .h file with a bunch of declarations like these. Anyway, replaced it with (x+1)-1, ugly but will have to do =\

Comment: Well.. just so you know, MSDN (from the link above) says: `You can avoid C4146 by using INT_MIN from limits.h, which has the type signed int.` You could just make your script replace `-2147483648` with `INT_MIN`.

Comment: You can [*Suppress Compiler Warnings*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx). Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ negative numbers are stored as positive number with (-) negative sign.

That is why min int is defined as,

`#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)`

For int C++ does not understand  *2147483648*. So if possible you can also write  *2147483648* as *(-2147483647 - 1)*

Comment: I guess I'll have to, even if it requires an ugly hack in the script that generates the code. However, I still don't understand why it generated an *error* instead of just a warning.

Comment: The way negative numbers are stored is implementation-defined, with 3 options: 2's-complement, 1's-complement, and sign-and-magnitude. Only sign-and-magnitude actually stores negative numbers just by setting the sign bit -- and 2's-complement is practically universal these days.

Answer (score 1):

An unsuffixed decimal integer literal like `2147483648` is of type `int`, `long int`, or `long long int`, specifically the first of those types in which its value can be represented.

On a system with 32-bit `int`, `2147483648` will be of type `long int` or `long long int`.

But your compiler's warning message indicates that it's following a different set of rules. In the 1990 C standard, an unsuffixed decimal integer constant is of type `int`, `long int`, or `unsigned long int` (there was no type `long long`). So under C90 rules, `2147483648` would likely be of type `unsigned long int`. Applying the unary `-` operator to it doesn't change the type, and under the rules of unsigned arithmetic the result is `2147483648`.

Although the rule that such a literal is of type `int` or `long int` is present in the 1998, 2003, and 2011 ISO C++ standards, you seem to be using a compiler that behaves inconsistently with any of those standards.

If your template expects an `int`, then the `unsigned long int` value `2147483648` will be implicitly converted to `int`. The result of such a conversion (when the value exceeds `INT_MAX` is implementation-defined, but is very likely to be `-2147483648`, which is `INT_MIN` for a 32-bit 2's-complement system.

You say the C++ source is generated by a Python script, and that the value isn't necessarily `-2147483648`. I think you'll just have to add a special case so that the value `-2147483648` is generated as `(-2147483647-1)`.  (I do recommend the parentheses; they're not necessary in this particular case, but they're harmless and can avoid operator precedence problems if you generate similar constants in other contexts.)

Note that the values of `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` can vary for different implementations. If you might need to target different C++ implementations, you should probably make your Python script smart enough to deal with different bounds.