# How the unary minus operator works with integer literals in C++?

Tags: c++, literals

I read that decimal literals are signed by default.
For simplicity, assume that the values that `int` can hold are the integers [-128,127], and `long` can hold the integer 128. Now, what happens if I code the literal -128? What I know is that the literal here is simply ‘128’, which can't fit into an `int` but rather would go into a `long`! or does the unary minus operator do something else?
So, how does the unary minus sign work with integer literals?

Comment: The unary `-`  is used in an expression.   So `-128` applies the unary `-` to the decimal literal `128`,   and gives a negative result.  Since `128` has type `int`, so does `-128`.     And since the `int` type is guaranteed to be able to represent any value in the range `-32767` to `32767`, there is no need for conversions.  An `int` can represent `128` or `-128` - guaranteed.

Comment: @Peter Does it mean, that `int i = -2147483648;` requires a conversion with 32-bit `int`? UPDATE: It's discussed here: [How do I define a constant equal to -2147483648?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27612996/580083).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal):

> The type of the integer literal is the first type in which the value can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base and which *integer-suffix* was used.

When using a decimal base and no suffix, as in your example, the possible types are `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`. If the value (ignoring the minus sign) fits in a `long` but not in an `int`, then the type of the value is `long`.

After the type is determined, the unary minus operator is applied as normal. Applying unary minus to a `long` results in a `long` (even if the result could fit in an `int`).